# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'votables.question_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hello guys i am stuck with problem with 1 course. This is the error which i get :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'votables.question_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `votables`.`question_id` as `pivot_question_id`, `votables`.`votable_id` as `pivot_votable_id`, `votables`.`votable_type` as `pivot_votable_type` from `users` inner join `votables` on `users`.`id` = `votables`.`votable_id` where `votables`.`question_id` in (2) and `votables`.`votable_type` = App\Models\User)
```

I made Polymorphic Relationship from User Model , Question Model and Answer Model into table "votables"

```
**User DB migration:**
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Question DB migration:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('answers')->default(0);
            $table->integer('votes_count')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

and Votables DB migration:

```
Schema::create('votables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('votable_id');
            $table->string('votable_type');
            $table->tinyInteger('vote')->comment('-1: down vote, 1: up vote');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(['user_id', 'votable_id', 'votable_type']);
        });
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/questions/{question}/vote', VoteQuestionController::class);
```

VoteQuestionController :

```
public function __invoke(Question $question){
        $vote = (int) request()->vote;
        auth()->user()->voteQuestion($question, $vote);

        return back();
    }
```

and Models - User

```
public function voteQuestions(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(Question::class, 'votable');
    }

    public function voteAnswers(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(Answer::class, 'votable');
    }

    public function voteQuestion(Question $question, $vote){
        $voteQuestions = $this->voteQuestions();
        if($voteQuestions->where('votable_id', $question->id)->exists()){
            $voteQuestions->updateExistingPivot($question, ['vote' => $vote]);
        }
        else{
            $voteQuestions->attach($question, ['vote' => $vote]);
        }

        $question->load('votes');
        $downVotes = (int) $question->downVotes()->sum('vote');
        $upVotes = (int) $question->upVotes()->sum('vote');
        dd($upVotes);
        $question->votes_count = $upVotes + $downVotes;

        $question->save();
    }
```

and Question model:

```
public function votes(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'votable');
    }

    public function upVotes(){
        return $this->votes()->wherePivot('vote', 1);
    }

    public function downVotes(){
        return $this->votes()->wherePivot('vote', -1);
    }
```

So after clicking the button from auth user to vote some question i get in db:

https://prnt.sc/wnbak9

But in questions table they didnt count and i get that error after click. Some suggestions?

Comment: You miss the relation (foreign) between votables and questions

Comment: You have pivot relations but no pivot table

Comment: votables is mine pivot table. Anyway i find the mistake in Question i made polymorph relation to User with morphedByMany , but need to be morphToMany :)